# Which of the following numbers can be orders of a permutation $\sigma$ of $11$ symbols

Tags: permutations

Which of the following numbers can be orders of a permutation $\sigma$ of $11$ symbols, such that $\sigma$ does not fix any symbols?

$1. \;18$

$2.\; 30$

$3.\;15$

$4.\; 28$

could any one just give me hints?

Comment: What do you know about the order of a permutation?

Comment: length of the permutation is its order.

Comment: What is the order of $(1 2)(3 4 5)$?

Comment: $6$, in this case I need to take lcm of order of the cycle

Comment: OK so can you get a cycle pattern on 11 symbols with lcm equal to the various target values?

Comment: I can get a permutation which is  product of a $5$ cycle and a $6$ cycle hence $30$ will be an answer? similarly a $7$ cycle and a $4$ cycle hence $28$ will be another answer? and a $9$ cycle and a transposition. so $18$ will be another answer

Comment: Looks good to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about the orders of the permutations (1 2) (3 4 5) and (1 2) (3 4 5 6) and see if you can think of a rule that gives the order of a permutation written in disjoint cycle notation. Now if $\sigma$ fixes no points, what does it tell you about the permutation written in disjoint cycle notation? From this you should be able to tell which orders are possible.

Comment: $18,30,28$ will be the answers, thank you

Comment: @TaxiDriver - you perhaps need to look more carefully at 15 - hint you can have as many cycles as you like.

Comment: Close, but not quite. Can you give permutations that have these orders? Also can you say why order 15 is impossible?

Comment: well, I am not able to find an element of $S_{11}$ whose order is $15$

Comment: what were your elements for the other orders?

Comment: There are definitely elements of order $15$ in $S_{11}$, but finding one which fixes no points is, perhaps, a little harder.

Comment: any $5,6$ cycle(disjoint), any $9,2$ cycle(disjoint), any $7,4$ cycle(disjoint).

Comment: I am not able to see why $15$ will be also an answer, it would be great if some one tell me clearly, have exam very near :)

Comment: an element of order 15 would have to have either 15-cycles or 5-cycles and 3-cycles (or some combination). Now it's just a matter of finding a combination of such cycles whose lengths sum to 11. 11=5+3+3 so we could have (1 2 3 4 5)(6 7 8)(9 10 11) as an example

Comment: @john Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Firstly find all partitions of 11 as follows:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
                                 & \text{ corresponding l.c.m }   \\       
   11                          &11\\
10+1.                        &10 (\text{l.cm of }10,1)\\
9+2.                          & 18 \text{l.cm of }9,2 \\
9+1+1\\
8+3\\
8+2+1\\
8+1+1+1\\
.\\
.7+4\\
.\\
.\\
6+5\\
6+4+1\\
.\\
.\\
5+5+1\\
.....\\
5+ 3+2\\
5+3+1+1+1.    &          15( \text{l.c.m of }  5,3,1,1)\\
.......\\
\text{Similarly up to } 1+1.....+1 \ (11 \text{times})\\
\end{array}    $$
When we calculate l.c.m in all above cases we see 28 l.c.m is not possible 
So possible answers are 18,15,30

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).